# Delay first 3 items by 1 second and the fourth by 4 seconds

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to display the first 3 numbers each one delayed by 1 second and the fourth one by 4 seconds. Unfortunately, my code displays the four numbers by 1 second

```
import { from, of, race, timer, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { groupBy, mergeMap, toArray, map,merge, reduce, concatMap, delay, concat, timeout, catchError, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const obs$ = from([1,2,3]).pipe(concatMap(a => of(a).pipe(delay(1000)))); 
const obs2$ = of(4).pipe(delay(4000)); 
const result$ = obs$.pipe(merge(obs2$));

const subscribe = result$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

It displays
1234|

instead of
123----4|

this question is entirely for learning rxjs as beginner and has been tested on https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**METHOD 1**

The `merge` operator subscribes to both observable (`obs$` and `obs2$`) **at the same time**. Therefore the result you get from your code may be explained as follows:

```
obs$     -----1-----2-----3
obs2$    -----------------------4
result$  -----1-----2-----3-----4
```

You may achieve your goal by forcing `merge` to subscribe only one observable at a time by providing the second argument as 1 (which is `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` by default) like the following:

```ts
    const obs$ = from([1,2,3]).pipe(concatMap(a => of(a).pipe(delay(1000)))); 
    const obs2$ = of(4).pipe(delay(4000));
    // Provide the concurrency (second) argument as 1 
    const result$ = obs$.pipe(merge(obs2$, 1));

const subscribe = result$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

**METHOD 2**

Use `concat` instead of `merge`:

```
 const obs$ = from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(concatMap(a => of(a).pipe(delay(1000))));
    const obs2$ = of(4).pipe(delay(4000));
    const result$ = concat(obs$, obs2$);

    const subscribe = result$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

**METHOD 3**

Otherwise you simply make use of the second parameter of `concatMap` which is the index (starts from 0) of emitted items.

```ts
 const obs$ = from([1, 2, 3, 4]);

        const delayed$ = obs$.pipe(
          concatMap((value, index) => {
            if (index <= 2) {
              // Delay the first 3 items by 1 sec
              return of(value).pipe(delay(1000));
            } else {
              // Delay other items (here the 4th item) by 4 sec
              return of(value).pipe(delay(4000));
            }
          })
        );

        delayed$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: your answer totally rocks, really clear. Thanks man, you're great ! I didn't think merge would subscribe to both observable, but actually it's logical.